# Measure theory and Large numbers

Tags: probability

It is known that if $X$ takes only non-negative integer values, then 
$$E[X]=\sum_{k=0}^\infty P(X>k).$$
Now how would I show that for any non-negative random variable $X$ 
$$E[X] < \sum_{k=0}^\infty P(X>k) < E[X]+1.$$

Comment: By $<$ do you mean $\leq$?

Comment: yes I do @voldemort

Answer (score 2):

Use the ceiling function.  The "ceiling" of a real number $x$ is the smallest integer greater than or equal to $x$.  For example, the ceiling of $7.43$ is $8$, and the ceiling of $8$ is $8$.  The ceiling of $x$ is denoted $\lceil x\rceil$.

Since $X\le\lceil X\rceil\le X+1$, we have $\mathbb E(X) \le \mathbb E(\lceil X\rceil)\le \mathbb E(X)+1$.  Since $\lceil X\rceil$ is integer-valued, we have
$$
\mathbb E(\lceil X\rceil) = \sum_{x=0}^\infty \Pr(\lceil X\rceil > x). \tag 1
$$
But then notice that if $x$ is a non-negative integer then $\lceil X\rceil > x$ if and only if $X>x$, so $(1)$ is equal to
$$
\sum_{x=0}^\infty \Pr(X>x).
$$